# Multi-level graph three like combination?

Tags: python, graph

I've been scratching my head with this a few weeks now and just can't get it right.
So let's say you have a few elements each digit is a index
0

```
0
    0
        0
            0
            0
            1
        0
        1
            0
            1
            2
        2
            0
                0
                1
            1
```

each of these digits is a index, each new element is on a new line and depending on the ident belongs to the upper indented element. Now what's I'm trying to achieve is all the possible combinations for example row 4 and 5 combined with row 3 and 6. You can see what's my current progress in the following code.

```
    a = """0
>0
>>0
>>>0
>>>1
>>>1
>>0
>>>0
>>>>0
>1
>>0
>>>0
>>>1
>>>1
>>>2
>>0
>>>0
>>>0
>>1
>>>0
>>>1
>>>1
>>>2
>>>2
>>1"""
class element:
    def __init__(self,ident,index,row):
        self.ident = ident
        self.index = index
        self.row = row
        self.id = None
e = []
count=0
#possibilities
def printElement(element):
    print("\t"*element.ident,element.index,element.row,end=" ")
def possibilities(element):
    row = element.row
    index = -2
    row+=1
    while(row<len(e)):
        if(e[row].ident<=element.ident):
            break
        if(e[row].ident == element.ident+1):
            index = e[row].index
        row+=1
    return index+1

for x in a.split("\n"):
    e.append(element(x.count(">"),int(x[-1]),count))
    count+=1
def find_id(element):
    row = element.row
    while(not(row == 0)):
        if(element.ident>e[row].ident):
            return e[row]
        row-=1
for x in range(1,len(e)):
    e[x].id = find_id(e[x])

for x in e:
    printElement(x)
    print(possibilities(x))
def get_matrix(ident):
    arr = []
    for x in e:
        if(x.ident == ident):
            arr.append(x)
    return arr

arr = []
for x in range(5):
    arr.append(get_matrix(x))
#test function
def test():
    arr2 = []
    for x in range(possibilities(e[10])):
        arr3 = []
        for y in arr[3]:
            if(y.index == x):
                arr3.append(y)
        arr2.append(arr3)
    print("starting")
    for x in arr2:
        print("")
        for y in x:
            printElement(y)
            print("")
class id:
    def __init__(self,id,element):
        self.id = id
        self.elements = [element]
        self.one=[]
        self.two=[]
        self.three=[]
    def gid(self):
        return self.id
    def divide(self):
        for x in self.elements:
            if(x.index==0):
                self.one.append(x)
            if(x.index==1):
                self.two.append(x)
            if(x.index==2):
                self.three.append(x)
def contains(list, filter):
    for x in list:
        if(filter == x.id):
            return True
    return False
def find(list,filter):
    count = 0
    for x in list:
        if(filter == x.id):
            return count
        count+=1
def ids(array):
    ids = []
#map
#iterate through first than iterate through second then third
#if they have same id and index they are togheter
    for x in array:
        if(contains(ids,x.id)):
            ids[find(ids,x.id)].elements.append(x)
        else:
            ids.append(id(x.id,x))
    for x in ids:
        x.divide()
    return ids
len(arr)
idss = []
for x in arr:
    idss.append(ids(x))
#looking for 8 recepies

for x in idss:
    print(len(x))
for x in arr:
    print("")
    for y in x:
        print(str(y.row)+" ",end = "")
```

desired output an array of all the possible combinations, should contain the elements class
for the above example:
[0,1,2,3,6],[0,1,2,5,6],[0,1,7,8],[0,1,7,9],[0,1,7,10],[0,1,11,12,13],[0,1,11,14]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that wants the answer:
You use a que and a brute force algorithm, just as you would in a normal graph, but combine all the elements in the downer two rows

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).